# Move an image towards a point with maximum speed

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I watched a video on swarm intelligence and wanted to make a small simulation of agents delivering resources to a base. The rules given by the video said they have to turn towards "a point".
I tried to make it manually but that quickly became 50 lines of code that didn't work. So I searched the internet and this is what I found:

```
let x = Destination.X - agent.X;
let y = Destination.Y - agent.Y;
let angle = Math.atan2(y, x);
let mag = 7.07106781;
let velX = Math.cos(angle) * mag;
let velY = Math.sin(angle) * mag;
agent.xVel = velX;
agent.YVel = velY;
```

It didn't work and they just ended up moving around aimlessly so I tried to set the `mag` to 5 since that was the max speed I wanted. Which didn't work either.

**SO is there any way to make a rectangle on a canvas move towards a point with a maximum speed?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't understand the final target of your question, so this is the code that makes rectangle move to point (cursor) at their max speed.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const pr = window.devicePixelRatio;
canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth * pr;
canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight * pr;
let lastTs = null;

const objects = [
  {
    x: 10*pr, y: 10*pr, color: "#f7a", s: 5 * pr,
    speed: {x: 0, y: 0, max: 2000},
    accel: {x: 0, y: 0, max: 20000}
  },
  {
    x: 500*pr, y: 150*pr, color: "#7fa", s: 7 * pr,
    speed: {x: 0, y: 0, max: 1000},
    accel: {x: 0, y: 0, max: 10000}
  }
]

const point = {x: 20, y: 20, active: false};

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  point.x = e.offsetX * pr;
  point.y = e.offsetY * pr;
  point.active = true;
});

canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
  point.active = false;
});

const drawCursor = () => {
  if (point.active){
    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(point.x, point.y, 3*pr, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
  }
};

const moveAndDrawObject = (o, dt) => {
  if (point.active){
    const phi = Math.atan2(point.y - o.y, point.x - o.x);
    o.accel.x = Math.cos(phi) * o.accel.max;
    o.accel.y = Math.sin(phi) * o.accel.max;
  } else {
    o.accel = {...o.accel, x: 0, y: 0};
  }
  o.speed.x += o.accel.x * dt;
  o.speed.y += o.accel.y * dt;
  const absSpeed = Math.hypot(o.speed.x, o.speed.y);
  if (absSpeed > o.speed.max){
    o.speed.x = o.speed.x * o.speed.max / absSpeed;
    o.speed.y = o.speed.y * o.speed.max / absSpeed;
  }
  o.x += o.speed.x * dt;
  o.y += o.speed.y * dt;
  ctx.fillStyle = o.color;
  ctx.fillRect(o.x - o.s, o.y - o.s, o.s * 2, o.s * 2);
};

const draw = () => {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#333";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawCursor();
  const now = Date.now() / 1000;
  const dt = (lastTs == null ? 0 : now - lastTs);
  lastTs = now;
  objects.forEach(o => moveAndDrawObject(o, dt));
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
};

draw();
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 700px;
  height: 190px;
  border: 1px #999 solid;
}

h3 { color: #999; margin-left: 5px; margin-top: -30px}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<h3>move mouse over canvas</h3>
```

You can increase the `accel.max` of object to make it move more straight to point if you want.
You also can remove mouse handlers to make point static.